# Slick generated schema code adds an unwanted ON UPDATE trigger to field.

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am using Slick 3.1.1 with MySql 5.6.33.

I executed [schema code generation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/code-generation.html) to generate the code for representing the 'invoices' table in our production server.
Here is a segment of the generated code.

```
class Invoices(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[InvoicesRow](_tableTag, "invoices") {
...
  /** Database column created_at SqlType(DATETIME) */
  val createdAt: Rep[java.sql.Timestamp] = column[java.sql.Timestamp]("created_at")
  /** Database column updated_at SqlType(DATETIME) */
  val updatedAt: Rep[java.sql.Timestamp] = column[java.sql.Timestamp]("updated_at")
...}
```

I then create the table locally, using the generated code (as explained [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html)), and found that the created table contains the following 2 columns:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

However, the same columns of the 'invoices' table in the production server, are defined without the default value or the ON UPDATE trigger:

```
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
```

These discrepancies causes my tests to fail because every time I update a row, the field 'created_at' is updated too with the current timestamp (while I need the field to keep it's existing value).

Why do these discrepancies exist? Why does Slick add the '**ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**' segment? Is there a way to stop Slick from adding the '**ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**', or at-least a way to remove the 'ON UPDATE' definition from the table (after it's creation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fay to force the column definition. I had to edit the generated code by hand:

```
  val createdAt = column[java.sql.Timestamp]("created_at", SqlType("datetime not null"))
```

[This blog post](http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-slick-dealing-with-datetime-timestamp-attributes) assisted me.